# Fill correctly a IQueryable model with linq join

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have to show data on a `listview` item, so I have the following code behind:

```
public IQueryable mostrarMesas()
{
    var query = from area in db.res_areas_sucursal
                join mesa in db.res_mesas_sucursal on area.area_gkey equals mesa.area_gkey
                select mesa;

    return query;
}
```

This joins two tables data and returns the data I need, but I need to show data from both tables, I tried creating this model that I think has what I need

```
public class Mesas
{
    [Key]
    public long? mesa_gkey { get; set; }

    public String descripcion_mesa { get; set; }

    public res_areas_sucursal res_areas_sucursal { get; set; }

    public int total_capacidad { get; set; }

    public bool disponible_para_reserva { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't know how to assign the query to return a list of `Mesas` objects instead of the ones from the entity framework. I'm using ASP.NET Webforms 4.5

How could I do this?

Should I establish the relations on the database first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous types:

```
var query = from area in db.res_areas_sucursal
            join mesa in db.res_mesas_sucursal on area.area_gkey equals mesa.area_gkey
            select new { area, mesa } ;
            return query;
```

Or you can use your model:

```
var query = from area in db.res_areas_sucursal
                join mesa in db.res_mesas_sucursal on area.area_gkey equals mesa.area_gkey
                select new Mesas()
                {
                   mesa_gkey = mesa.gkey,
                   // continue the rest
                };

                return query;
```

Inside the select, you can use both `area` and `mesa`. Then you can select whatever properties (columns) you need and assign them.

Note that it is better to return `IQueryable<Mesas>` instead of just `IQueryable` unless you have a valid reason not to do so.

Comment: A simple comment like  "use the LINQ select operator" would be sufficient. Answering basic questions that lack elementary research, really?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry I didn't knew exactly how to search for this, I looked up for joining tables using linq, and I came up with the join clause and other things I already implemented, was missing this step

Comment: @Forcefield Personal advice - always start with MSDN:  [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), [Query Keywords (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx) etc.